# ROracle is not handling Unicode

Tags: r, oracle

I'm using ROracle to query a database with a VARCHAR2 field containing some Unicode characters. When I access the database directly or via RJDBC, I have no issues with pulling this data.

When I pull the data with ROracle, I get ????? instead of the text.

Comment: did you also try cast it into `VARCHAR2`? AFAIK in JDBC all strings are represented/returned as UTF16 - as this is the only representation of String in JVM. While in OCI both `VARCHAR2` and `NVARCHAR2` have the same typecode id, but `NVARCHAR2` has additional attribute set. So in OCI these two types can be easily mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for that info... I created a table with a VARCHAR2 field but with some UTF8 characters and it again renders fine in sql developer or RJDBC but not in ROracle. So now I guess it is clearer that the problem is not NVARCHAR. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OCI you have use env. variable NLS_LANG. For example: 
    `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

will make OCI client return all strings returned in UTF8. This should work, if internal string representation in R also uses UTF8. Then ROracle can make simple binary copy from one buffer into another buffer.

Oracle uses question marks in case when it can not translate char into target code page.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can set this variable in OCI? (I'm not too familiar with it, only using it so I can use ROracle)

Comment: It's environment variable. You should set it before you start R.

Comment: I had to export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 and then reinstall ROracle. That fixed it. Thanks!!